# How to convert ReportServer.dbo.CatalogItemExtendedContent.Content to readable string?

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

Is it possible to obtain the report definition (or perhaps DataMashup file equivalent) of Power BI reports via the ReportServer database?

SSRS reports (ReportServer.dbo.Catalog.Content) convert nicely but the titular column less so.

I tried converting to xml but there's a parsing error and conversion to (n)varchar yields gobbledygook.

Comment: What makes you think it's meant to be readable content? My understanding was that this often stores .pbix file data which is essentially a PK-zip archive containing many other folders and files.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, fair enough. I was just wondering if it could become readable content. Thanks.